# Drop a variable from a SAS dataset based on a condition (IF THEN DO)

Tags: sas, sas-macro

So I've done some searching around online but haven't managed to find anything that can solve this problem. Essentially, I have been given a dataset that I've then split into individual dataset's based on name.

However, if the person is a female, the age needs to be omitted from the dataset. Example output:

**Males**

Name    Age     Weight     Height

**Females**

Name      Weight       Height

I have tried the following IF statement, but it just seems to drop the age variable from both the male and female tables:

```
if sex="F" then do;
    drop age;
end;
```

I'm fairly new to SAS so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

When you run a data step in SAS, some statements are processed during compilation, and others subsequently during execution. In this case, the `drop` statement is processed before your `if-then` logic, so you can't use it to conditionally drop a column.

Alternatively, you could output a missing value for `age` for each affected row, e.g.

```
if sex = 'F' then call missing(age);
```

Or you could use a drop clause on one output dataset but not the other:

```
data boys girls(drop=age);
  set sashelp.class;
  if sex = 'F' then output girls;
  else if sex = 'M' then output boys;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The 'call missing(age)' method works great in omitting age observations from the dataset. However, what I actually want to do is remove the variable entirely. So imagine there are 19 names, therefore there are 19 new datasets once the original dataset has been split. If the person is a female, then the age variable should be removed from each individual female dataset. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Generally in SAS one should always avoid splitting datasets like that. It is much easier to work with a single big dataset and appropriate `by` statements.

Comment: That said, I updated my answer to include an example of how to drop a column in one output dataset but not another.

Answer (score 0):

The DROP statement cannot be run conditionally. You need to conditionally generate the DROP statement (or DROP= dataset option).

To use a trivial example dataset let's start with `SASHELP.CLASS` and split it into individual datasets.  Note that this dataset only has one observation per NAME, but I will add BY group processing to the code generation step so you can see how you could use it in the case where there are multiple observations per name.

First let's generate code for single DATA statement that creates multiple output datasets.  Based on the value of the SEX variable it will conditionally add a DROP= dataset option.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class end=eof ;
  by name ;
  file code ;
  if _n_=1 then put 'data' ;
  if first.name then do;
    put '  ' name @ ;
    if sex='F' then put '(drop=age)' @ ;
    put ;
  end;
  if eof then put ';' ;
run;
```

Now let's append the code for the rest of the data step that will read the source dataset and output the records to the appropriate dataset.

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class end=eof ;
  by name ;
  file code mod ;
  if _n_=1 then put '  set sashelp.class; ' ;
  if first.name then put '  if name =' name $quote. 'then output ' name ';' ;
  if eof then put 'run;' ;
run;
```

Finally run the generated code.

```
%include code / source2 ;
```

Comment: Seems like a pretty complicated/roundabout way of doing things.  Would it not be easier to simply drop the column from the generated table afterwards rather than going to this trouble?  Or use a macro?  Or even better use user667's approach?